# Input fields that relate to a scoring system?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible (I'm sure it is!) to have a system whereby if you alter the first field, the value in there affects the second field? For example:

```
Position [  ]  Points [  ]
Position [  ]  Points [  ]
Position [  ]  Points [  ]
```

You have 10 or so of these fields and each relate to each other. If you enter 1 in to position, the points field should pre-populate with 20 points, if you enter 2 then it pre-populates with the related value, then to relate this to all of the rows?

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive with what you are trying to achieve. Is that code or a sample screen representation?

Comment: If i understand what you mean, it shouldn't be very hard to use an onchange event to get the value of the input field, the make the proper calculations and then set the values for the other related fields.

Comment: It's a screen representation. I thought about using an onchange function, but my mind went blank at this point: function `changePos(intValue){
 var position1 = $('#Position1').val();
 if ( $('#Position1').val() == position1 ) {
   $("#Points1").val(20.val());
 }
}`

Comment: This sounds something a MVVM framework like [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) can do easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will get you moving in the right direction:

```
$('#position1').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '1') {
        $('#points1').val('20');
    }
});
```

the logic can just get more complex if you want to relate more fields to the value of that one.  Hopefully this helps.

Here's a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qLM2n/4/)

Comment: Thanks for this, it works brilliantly for one row of the 2 fields: http://jsfiddle.net/qLM2n/2/ but how do I then add this to multiple rows, like this http://jsfiddle.net/qLM2n/3/ ?

Comment: does each position have the same related points?  Like would a position of 1 give a 20 points for all of them?

Comment: Yep, although only one can have position 1. The point scoring stays the same.

Comment: thanks!  that's the best way I've thought to do it.  I hope it helped!

Comment: To reduce the amount of code you could use an object for a map and get rid of all the `if` statements. http://jsfiddle.net/qLM2n/5/

Comment: nice, that might also make maintenance easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JS Fiddle, I'm using the change event in jquery on the first input to run an if statement to place a value in the second input.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#position').change(function(){
       if($('#position').val()=="1"){$('#points').val("20");}
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zc4yJ/